# Limit result of two different SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, limit

When you have a table you can limit the amount of results. But I have two tables:

This is the first one:

```
$requests_q = mysql_query("SELECT ava_users.*
FROM ava_friend_requests
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friend_requests.from_user = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friend_requests.to_user = $user[id]");
```

This is the second one:

```
$friends_q = mysql_query("SELECT ava_users.*
FROM ava_friends
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]");
```

This is the table definition for ava_friend_requests:

```
Field       Type                    Null    Key     Default     Extra
id          int(11) unsigned        NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
from_user   int(11)                 YES     MUL     NULL    
to_user     int(11)                 YES     MUL     NULL
```

This is the table definition for ava_friends:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra
user1   int(11) NO      MUL     NULL    
user2   int(11) NO      MUL     NULL
```

I'd like to limit the results in a way as if there was no second query (i.e. two queries but ONE LIMITED RESULT ONLY). I was searching the net but couldn't find anything so far. I'm not sure if UNION can help me in this case.

Comment: Please post the table definitions

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample data and the result you are expecting.

Comment: Is there no way to join `ava_friend_requests` to `ava_friends` so you could get all the data at once?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the tables having different columns - a UNION (or more accurately `UNION ALL`) should work as it only matters what you select, which is the same.

Comment: Ok. I added the table definitons and discoverd that the columns seem to be identical. I updated my post and corrected that mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$union_q = mysql_query(
    "SELECT ava_users.*
     FROM ava_friend_requests
     LEFT JOIN ava_users 
     ON ava_friend_requests.from_user = ava_users.id
     WHERE ava_friend_requests.to_user = $user[id]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ava_users.*
     FROM ava_friends
     LEFT JOIN ava_users 
     ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
     WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]
     LIMIT 0, 10");
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Sylvain Leroux in the comments, the order of results returned by the union isn't guaranteed to be all those from the first query followed by all rows from the second query. If this is an issue for you, would suggest modifying the query to order the records, e.g as follows:

```
SELECT ava_users.*, 0 AS ord
FROM ava_friend_requests
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friend_requests.from_user = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friend_requests.to_user = $user[id]
UNION ALL
SELECT ava_users.*, 1 AS ord
FROM ava_friends
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]
ORDER BY ord
LIMIT 0, 10
```

(If you don't want to include the `ord` field in the SELECT, it's possible by making the whole thing into a subquery but that'd make it more complex and is probably getting outside the scope of the original question.)

Comment: You are assuming here than `UNION` are executed from left to right. As far as I know there is no such guarantee with MySQL. To cite the official documentation Union "by default produces an unordered set of rows." Depending your luck (or the path taken by the query optimizer) this might work or not...

Comment: I'll check it out ASAP!:D

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Good point, although I'm not sure whether this would be a concern or not from the original question. Have edited my answer with a suggestion for how to order the results if this is important.

Comment: @SteveChambers Much better with explicit ordering! I re-read the question and, as I understand it, order *is* important. Otherwise, at worst, you could have 10 rows from the "right part" of the `UNION` and none of the "left part". Whereas the OP want the exact opposite. As it is now enforced by your solution ;)

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux: Yes - ordering is very important because in one table there are 'friend requests' and the other table contains 'friends' only. If the result is not ordered everything gets screwed up.

Comment: @Steve Chambers: Doesn't seem to work. It produces an array that has duplicates inside of it. Before the UNION I had 'friends' and 'friend requests'. In my database I have two 'friend requests' and four 'friends'. Now I have 'friend requests' ONLY (6). This seems to be pretty complicated and to be honest I have no idea how to solve this due to the fact that I have basic SQL-experiences only. Is there a possibility to solve this situation with a mathematical formula?

Comment: @drpelz Not sure what you mean - it isn't complicated, all it does is combine the results of both queries and then limit the number of results returned. If you want to remove exact duplicates you could use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` but I can't really tell from your comment if this is what the problem is.

Comment: @Steve Chambers: This might be a dumb question but I'd like to know why do you SELECT 0 AS ord (and SELECT 1 AS ord respectively)?

Comment: @drpelz To make sure everything in the first query appears before everything in the second query (since 0 < 1 and `ORDER BY` orders by value in ascending order).